# How to prove Laplace transform is of an existing function

Tags: laplace-transform

> How to prove this $$\frac{s}{(s^2+4)^2}$$ is the Laplace transform of a continuous exponential $f(x)$?

I understand how to solve the problem the other way around (given $f(x)$ you prove that the convolution of $ e^{-st} f(x) $ converges) but how do you approach the problem when given the Laplace transform and have to prove it is in fact an existing function that produced it?

Comment: Because the question is to prove that the inverse function exists. At least that's how I understand it. I am given the transform above and I am asked to prove that a continuous and exponential function exists which can be transformed into that. I believe I have to somehow prove the conditions are met (f(x) is partially continuous and exponential) using the transform.

Answer (score 1):

If you compare it with tables, you can discover that 
$$f(t)=\frac{t \sin (2 t)}{4} =\mathcal{L}^{-1}\!\left[\frac{s}{\left(s^2+4\right)^{\!2}}\right]. $$
To finish, take the Laplace transform of this $f(t)$ and show that you get the RHS.

Comment: I suppose this works but do you think there is a way to determine said function exists without actually using known transforms?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the inverse Laplace Transform:

$$\mathcal {L} \left\{f(t)\right \}= \left \{\frac{s}{(s^2+4)^2}\right \}$$
$$\mathcal {L} \left \{f(t)\right \}=\frac 1 2 \left \{\frac{2s}{(s^2+4)^2}\right \}$$
$$\mathcal {L} \left \{f(t)\right \}=-\frac 1 2\left \{\frac d {ds}\frac{1}{(s^2+4)}\right \}$$
$$\mathcal {L} \left \{f(t)\right \}=-\frac 1 4\left \{\frac d {ds}\frac{2}{(s^2+4)}\right \}$$
$$\mathcal {L} \left \{f(t)\right \}=-\frac 1 4\left \{\frac d {ds}\mathcal {L} \left \{\sin(2t) \right \}\right \}$$
$$\boxed {f(t)=\frac 1 4{t\sin(2t)}}$$